# Portable Browser Issues when deploying R Shiny App

Tags: windows, r, google-chrome, portability, shiny

I've built a complex Shiny interface that pulls from an internally networked ODBC table and allows a user to interact with the data through their browser. The company is on Windows 7 Enterprise and IT only supports IE 9. Some users have chrome installed in their user folders, some have firefox, some use IE 9. I followed a tutorial from R-Bloggers (here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/) and it runs on my machine using a portable Chrome browser downloaded from PortableApps.com. Great. Unfortunately the interface has not started on ANYONE else's machine that has their own local Chrome browser installed.

Following the tutorial, I use the following vb script:

```
Rexe           = "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe"
Ropts          = "--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole"
RScriptFile    = "runShinyApp.R"
Outfile        = "ShinyApp.log" 
strCommand     = Rexe & " " & Ropts & " " & RScriptFile & " 1> " & Outfile & " 2>&1"

intWindowStyle = 0     ' Hide the window and activate another window.'
bWaitOnReturn  = False ' continue running script after launching R   '

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run strCommand, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn
```

This script calls the following code in my R file:

```
message('library paths:\n', paste('... ', .libPaths(), sep='', collapse='\n'))
chrome.portable = file.path(getwd(),'GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe')
launch.browser = function(appUrl, browser.path=chrome.portable) {
    message('Browser path: ', browser.path)
    shell(sprintf('"%s" --app=%s', browser.path, appUrl))
}
shiny::runApp('shiny', launch.browser=launch.browser)
```

It works on my computer just fine... I DO have chrome installed locally, but I'm calling the Portable Chrome executable. It worries me that the two are sharing prefs or something, e.g. I notice that a hash from the Preferences file in my installed version, specifically:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
     "bookmarks": [ "chrome-extension://eemcgdkfndhakfknompkggombfjjjeno/main.html" ]
  },
```

...matches the same json entry from the Portable Chrome installation:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
     "bookmarks": [ "chrome-extension://eemcgdkfndhakfknompkggombfjjjeno/main.html" ]
  }
```

Why do these long random strings match? Am I barking up the wrong tree for wondering about this? I don't know why these strings match if they are two separate installations of Chrome executables, one of which is supposed to run completely independently from anything on the machine.

Here's a set of errors from one machine:

```
.../Desktop/TestApp3/GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe[9100:9408:0716/141934:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
[9100:9408:0716/141934:ERROR:component_loader.cc(138)] Failed to parse extension manifest.
[9100:1716:0716/141946:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(214)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
```

Here's a set of errors from a second machine:

```
.../Documents/TestApp3/GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe
[5220:3384:0714/142128:ERROR:component_loader.cc(138)] Failed to parse extension     manifest.
[5220:7600:0714/142130:ERROR:external_registry_loader_win.cc(136)] File C:\Program     Files\Coupons.com CouponBar\chrome\Coupons.com.crx for key     
Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\cnpkmcjgpcihgfnkcjapiaabbbplkcmf does not exist or is not readable.
[5220:2120:0714/142140:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(214)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[5220:3384:0714/142413:ERROR:CONSOLE(122)] "Could not find value for secondaryUser", source: chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js (122)
[5220:3384:0714/142413:ERROR:CONSOLE(122)] "[undefined] (secondaryUser) is not a boolean", source: chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js (122)
[5220:3384:0714/142425:ERROR:CONSOLE(122)] "Could not find value for secondaryUser", source: chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js (122)
[5220:3384:0714/142425:ERROR:CONSOLE(122)] "[undefined] (secondaryUser) is not a boolean", source: chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js (122)
[5220:3384:0714/142442:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(167)] Invalid entry with unique id: 12
```

It seems like Chrome is doing different things on different computers and is not actually acting as a standalone browser... but likely interacting with the browser installed on their respective computers via the registry or some other "under the hood, active" communication. Maybe, since I installed the portable executable on my machine, a bunch of my local extensions or preferences were automatically updated to the portable's preferences, etc. and subsequently this is causing a conflict on every other machine??

Can I shutdown Chrome's extensions or extra functions like the calls to the updater? Is there a better standalone portable browser that functions well with Shiny for this type of "deployment" purpose? Can I fix this or is this a lost cause?? This should be obvious but I'll say it anyway: it is definitely not economically efficient to ask the non-technical types to install R, then RStudio, then confirm their working directory structure, then call the `runApp()` command via the Script window...

Comment: I tried using the path "GoogleChromePortable/GoogleChromePortable.exe" instead of the longer path. Then I don't have such errors that you mentioned. But for me both versions do not even work on my computer (except inside the RStudio)

Comment: I finally solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31272180/1117932
My supervisor also found out what the difference is between the executables: If you update the chrome portable, "GoogleChromePortable/Chrome/chrome.exe" is updated and the other executables are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with those same articles, but developed the [RInno](https://ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno) package to solve this exact problem, i.e. when you want to share your desktop Shiny app with non-technical users who can't be expected to mess around with all those details.

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

This will create an installation wizard that runs like any other program, but installs your shiny app on a Windows desktop computer. If you would like to include R for your co-workers who don't have it installed, add `include_R = TRUE` to `create_app`:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp", include_R = TRUE)
```

It defaults to include shiny, magrittr and jsonlite, so if you are using other packages like ggplot2 or plotly, just add them to the `pkgs` argument. You can also include GitHub packages to the `remotes` argument:

```
create_app(
    app_name = "myapp", 
    app_dir  = "path/to/myapp"
    pkgs     = c("shiny", "jsonlite", "magrittr", "plotly", "ggplot2"),
    remotes  = c("talgalili/installr", "daattali/shinyjs"))
```

If you are interested in other features, check out [FI Labs - RInno](https://ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno)