# Creating stand-alone Shiny App - Chrome Error

Tags: r, google-chrome, batch-file, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny desktop app following the instruction of this very  nice blog post (http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/)

So basically I have a folder with the following structure:

```
App
|__ GoogleChromePortable
     |__ App
     |__ Data
     |__ ...
 |__ R Portable
     |__ App
     |__ Data
     |__ ...
|__ shiny
     |__ ui.R
     |__ server.R
     |__ ...
|__ LAUNCH.bat/LAUNCH.vbs
|__ runShinyApp.R
```

I am creating 2 different version, one with GoogleChromePortable and one without. Both versions are exactly the same apart from the path to Chrome in `runShinyApp.R`.

`runShinyApp.R`:

```
# checking if correct library paths are being used (only portable one!)
message('library paths:\n', paste('... ', .libPaths(), sep='',     collapse='\n'))

# both chromes work!
chrome.sys = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
chrome.portable = file.path(getwd(),
                        'GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe')

launch.browser = function(appUrl, browser.path=chrome.portable) {
message('Browser path: ', browser.path)
shell(sprintf('"%s" --app=%s', browser.path, appUrl))
}

shiny::runApp('./shiny/', launch.browser=launch.browser)
```

The app is launched through a `.bat` or `.vbs` file which are basically the same but for the fact that the first leaves a Commander Prompt window open.

`LAUNCH.bat`:

```
SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole
R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyApp.log 2>&1
```

`LAUNCH.vbs` :

```
Rexe           = "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe"
Ropts          = "--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-   Rconsole"
RScriptFile    = "runShinyApp.R"
Outfile        = "ShinyApp.log" 
strCommand     = Rexe & " " & Ropts & " " & RScriptFile & " 1> " & Outfile & " 2>&1"

intWindowStyle = 0     ' Hide the window and activate another window.'
bWaitOnReturn  = False ' continue running script after launching R   '

 ' the following is a Sub call, so no parentheses around arguments'
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run strCommand, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn
```

**Issue:**

The issue I am having is appearing in both versions and is the following.

IF I have my normal Chrome launched (NOT the portable version) installed on my system, the shiny app launches without any issues. It opens a new window entirely containing only the shiny app.

However IF I do *not* have a Chrome session open (default one), neither versions of the shiny seem to work. A window opens but loads forever.
Looking at the created logs, I get the following error:

```
[4092:3596:0621/154834:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://print/*
[4092:3596:0621/154834:ERROR:bluetooth_adapter_win.cc(102)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

Any idea what seems to be the issue here?

Comment: I never saw this method of deploying shiny apps. You know you can use shinyapps.io or just use your own shiny server, right? Hosting your own shiny server is very easy, I have a nice set of instructions if you need

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of the other ways of Shiny deployment. However for our project we would also like to share the shiny app with others so they can use there own laptop processing power but still without the fuss of installing anything.

Comment: @daattali could you post or link those instructions?

Comment: Sure, here it is 
http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

I don't know anything about this portable Chrome approach though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it that way with a few changes to **run.vbs** and **runShinyApp.R**.

**run.vbs:**

```
Rexe           = "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH"
Ropts          = "--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole "
RScriptFile    = "runShinyApp.R"
Outfile        = "ShinyApp.log"
startChrome    = "GoogleChromePortable\Chrome\chrome.exe --app=http://127.0.0.1:7777"
strCommand     = Rexe & " " & Ropts & " " & RScriptFile & " 1> " & Outfile & " 2>&1"

intWindowStyle = 0     ' Hide the window and activate another window.'
bWaitOnReturn  = False ' continue running script after launching R   '

' the following is a Sub call, so no parentheses around arguments'

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run strCommand, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run startChrome, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn
```

I added the `startChrome` variable and call `CreateObject` **after** I start the server, because otherwise there is no website and Chrome does not automatically reload when you start it afterwards. Usually starting the server should be fast enough but if you are on a very slow machine it might take too long. Then you need to add a delay between the two `CreateObject` calls.

The --app setting opens the app in a window that does not have all the Google Chrome buttons and then it really looks like a standalone app.

**runShinyApp.R:**

```
require(shiny)
shiny::runApp('./shiny/',port=7777)
```

Port 7777 is arbitrary, you can use any *free* port you like. The port has to be same in all files.

In case you want to use a **bat** file:

```
SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole
start /b GoogleChromePortable\Chrome\chrome.exe --app=http://127.0.0.1:7777
R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH %ROPTS% runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyAppOut.log 2> ShinyAppMsg.log
```

Comment: Verena, did you try your code in a Mac or could you please point me to a resource that can be of use for developing a standalone utility for a Mac using the same?

Comment: @bonCodigo As far as I know R Portable is only running on Windows. At least when I did this project it was only possible to do it on Windows. I'd love to see it working on Linux or Mac as well! If you find a portable R version for Mac then it should be possible to follow the same steps.

Answer (score 4):

I moved away from using the portable version of Chrome because of issues like this while developing the [RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) package, which is based on Dr. Lee Pang's DesktopDeployR framework. The package helps automate this and incorporates Inno Setup installers so that non-technical users can install and use your Shiny apps.

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

If you would like to include R for your co-workers who don't have it installed, add `include_R = TRUE` to `create_app`:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp", include_R = TRUE)
```

It defaults to include shiny, magrittr and jsonlite, so if you are using other packages like ggplot2 or plotly, just add them to the `pkgs` argument. You can also include GitHub packages to the `remotes` argument:

```
create_app(
    app_name = "myapp", 
    app_dir  = "path/to/myapp"
    pkgs     = c("shiny", "jsonlite", "magrittr", "plotly", "ggplot2"),
    remotes  = c("talgalili/installr", "daattali/shinyjs"))
```

If you are interested in other features, check out [FI Labs - RInno](http://www.ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno)

Comment: Could I still do "full" standalone with RInno using ChromePortable or something similar (at least a new browser window w/o any bars)? If so, how?

Comment: Not yet, but that is a great suggestion. Feel free to submit a feature request to https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues