# Standalone Shiny App (using R-Portable and GoogleChromePortable) error when using .vbs script

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a standalone shiny app for internal use and I also referred to the instructions on https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/ and http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html.

In my .vbs file, I added following code:

`Randomize CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False`

And when I run the .vbs script, it gives me error as shown in the picture:[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWMTG.png)

While, when I try to use the solution mentioned in the post [Creating stand-alone Shiny App - Chrome Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965410/creating-stand-alone-shiny-app-chrome-error/58414792#58414792), it does nothing.

Can someone please let me know how can I modify the .vbs script in order to be able to run the shiny app on a computer which does not have R installed?

I have also tried using RInno package but it doesn't work on my computer at step `RInno::install_inno()` because of its incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. So, I couldn't go further to use that solution too.